# What pattern matching technique is used by Maven/Surefire plugin when specifying tests in the <test> attribute within the <profile> attribute

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Given the following ...

```
    <profile>
        <id>mylogs</id>
        <properties>
            <test>**/foo/bar/logs/**</test>
            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

How could I change the  attribute to only run tests contained in class/java files containing characters 'MyLogsVer1*'?

Under the the folders /foo/bar/logs,  the filenames look something like 'MyLogsVer1Foo.java', 'MyLogsVer1Bar.java', 'MyLogsVer1Baz.java'.   There are also filenames 'MyLogsVer2BFoo.java', 'MyLogsVer2Bar.java' and 'MyLogsVer2Baz.java'.

I've tried specifying the path as ****/foo/bar/logs/MyLogsVer1*** but to no avail.

Comment: You should use the default naming convention for tests ... that means unit tests are named like `*Test.java` and integration tests named like `*IT.java` (with the support of maven-failsafe-plugin)...then those profile is not needed at all.. also test should be located in `src/test/java/<package>`... and your productive code in `src/main/java/<package>`...

Comment: Is the surefire plugin that inflexible that I must be coerced into its conventions?

Comment: The question is why you like to violate those best practices? ... What is the particular reason not to follow convention over configuration?

Comment: Well, I think I need rephrase this a bit...in the folder `foo/bar/baz`. there are tests, `BlahBlahVer1Test.java` and `BlahBlahBlahBlahVer2Test.java` surefire just looks for anything `*Test.java` How to specify in a particular profile `**\foo\bar\baz\*Ver2Test*`.  And to answer your question I do not necessarily like to violate those best practices, I'm looking for a way around a rather tedious refactor to split the different versions of tests into different folders...

Comment: If you have tests related to versions of dependencies the best way is to handle that via a multi module build and not via profiles and directories... also you could handle those different tests via tags/groups/suites etc. depending on what kind of unit testing framework you are using (but you don't have given such information)...